# Loading data that isnt on the route?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a dropdown setup on a form but how do i set it up if my data isnt in the route? I am trying to load in a list of territories on a new dealer form. I have added ember-power-select add on but I cant figure out how to load the data to the add on to display the available options. Do I need to create a service or controller?

New to ember just trying to work through the basics.

```
  Router.map(function() {
  this.route('login');
  this.route('admin', function() {
    this.route('territory', function() {
      this.route('new');
      this.route('edit', { path: '/:territory_id/edit'});
      this.route('view', { path: '/:territory_id/view'});
    });
    this.route('dealer', function() {
      this.route('view', { path: '/:dealer_id/view'});
      this.route('new');
    });
  });
});
```

This is my form I am using on creating a new item.

```
<div class="well">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>New Dealer</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                {{input type="text" value=model.dealerName class="form-control" placeholder="Dealer Name"}}
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Territory</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                {{#power-select  selected=dealer options=dealer onchange=(action "chooseDestination") as |dealer|}} 
                    {{dealer.dealerName}}  
                {{/power-select}}
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                {{#link-to 'admin.dealer' class="btn btn-default"}}Cancel{{/link-to}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" {{action 'saveDealer' model}}>Submit</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You dont need service or controller, you can use route itself. inside dealer.new route model hook you can use Ember.RSVP.hash ..if you require help i can write sample one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a route is the `new` action for a territory or the `view` action for a dealer, doesn't mean that you can't load other data there.

For example, in the `territory/view` route, you could load all the dealers.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      territory: this.store.find('territory', params.territory_id),
      dealers: this.store.findAll('dealer')
    })
  }
});
```

Then in your controller and templates, you would have access to `model.territory` and `model.dealers`